# Entity Framework Class Manipulation

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework (DB First) on a new project and wanted to add some customisation to the classes generated. However, my changes are obviously lost every time that the edmx is refreshed. I was just wondering if there is a design pattern for handling this sort of thing?

As an example, suppose I have a class with a integer property; StatusID - and I'd like to extend the entity class so that the status value can also be accessed/set via the related enum and finally a property that gets a text representation of that Enum from the description attribute. This all works, but those customisations are lost when the model is refreshed. I appreciate that the property can be converted to an enum, so the latter property that gets the description of the enum is perhaps a better example for this question.

I think I know the answer but I just wanted to put this out there in case there were some magic tricks that would allow this to work and prevent those customisations from being lost.

```
    public int StatusID { get; set; }

    public Enumerations.ValidationStatus StatusEnum
    {
        get
        {
            return (Enumerations.ValidationStatus)StatusID;
        }
        set
        {
            StatusID = (int)value;
        }
    }

    public string StatusText
    {
        get
        {
            return MyMethodThatGetsTheEnumDescription(StatusEnum);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Solutions to work around the problem:

1. User Data Transfer Object(DTO) nd put the enum there. then use Automapper or manually map between the DB Model and the DTO Model **(best practice)**
2. Instead of enum you can use extension functions on the model and define your getter, setters and any extra properties you want as extension functions to the class
   **(will add some complexity to your models)**